# Testing in go api call

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, automated-tests

I want to write test cases for my api like: database query fail,error in code,response error etc.

So I have created one file called controller_test.go in controllers folder.

here is my code:

```
    package controllers

    import (
       "net/http"
       "testing"
       "net/http/httptest"
     )

 func (imc ImessageSoundController) TestHealthCheckHandler(t *testing.T) {

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET","sound/imessage_sound", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(imc.ImessageSound)
    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)

    if status := rr.Code; status != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("handler returned wrong status code: got %v want %v",
            status, http.StatusOK)
    }
}
```

My api logic is written in code.go in controllers folder.
here is my code:

```
package controllers

import (
   //required packages
)

type (
    ImessageSoundController struct {
        session *sql.DB
    }
)

func NewImessageSoundController(s *sql.DB) *ImessageSoundController {
    return &ImessageSoundController{s}
}

func (imc ImessageSoundController) ImessageSound(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 //Code logic
}
```

I am getting this output for above case:

```
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
ok      tingtong2.1/controllers 0.004s
```

As I am new to this I am not able to find reason for this error.

Answer (score 0):

A test should be a function, not a method. Just make it:

```
func TestHealthCheckHandler(t *testing.T) {
    ...
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Ok then how I can call " func (imc ImessageSoundController) ImessageSound(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) " api method in http.HandlerFunc ?

Comment: You create an instance of struct ImessageSoundController inside the test function, configure it with desired values and then call the method in the test function.